# Max number of file in Fileupload Primefaces

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I set my FileUpload component with this params:

```
 <p:fileUpload label="Select image"  
                    mode="advanced"  
                    update="messages"  
                    fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                    sizeLimit="1000000"   
                    fileLimit="1"
                    fileLimitMessage="Only 1 image"
                    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/> 

  <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
```

But if i select more image i don't get any error or warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the same behavior, but I dont think it's intentional. You can do a little workaround if you use `auto="true"` because the file will be uploaded immediately. On the other hand you can make sure that your backing bean is just processing the **last** file uploaded (maybe the user selected a wrong file in the first place and wants to use another one?).

`fileLimit="1"` only limits the file limit when using `mode="advanced"` and `multiple="true"` (see [1]), but that is currently not supported by primefaces (see [2]).

[1] http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=14194

[2] https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf at page 218

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. To solve this i tried update="@this"

Answer (score 1):

fileLimit attribute is also not working in my case. I tried with mode="advanced" and multiple="true". In my case I want to limit the file to be uploaded upto 3. But it is not restricting me to upload more files.

Comment: Actually fileLimit of fileUpload has been removed from the Primefaces. I am using 3.4.2 version and it doesnt contain fileLimit though its still present in User Guide. I think user guide is not perfect. So if you want to use fileLimit try Primefaces 3.1